# Copy an oder list to another oder list

Tags: algorithm

Given a order list. Which supports only following operations.

```
insert(n)
Insert an element in tail only if n is greater than value of current tail otherwise throw exception

empty(n)
Check if list is empty 

remove()
remove an element from tail and return value
```

Given a order list as input. We need to write a function `copyList(source,destination)`, which copies one order list to another order list.

- We are not allowed to use any additional data structure.
- We can use at max one more temp order list.

I tried solving this problem but not getting any solution.

Comment: Sounds very [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)'ish to me.

Comment: only this three can be used? if so there is no way to make it fast.

Comment: Yes, It is Tower of Hanoi.